# Querying Opportunity Field History for a custop lookup fields gives 2 record back for a single change in the field

Tags: query, opportunity, opportunity-history

I am trying to query Opportunity Field History to get the results for a custom lookup field that has history tracking.
I am getting 2 records back for 1 single change, one of the record has oldvalue and newvalue as lookup id and another record has lookup name as old and new value. I was wondering why Field history is creating 2 records for same change. I am trying to query it and set the resulting list to a front end table, but since it is returning 2 values for single change there is a duplicate value displayed. how can i restrict that?

my query looks like this
select id, OldVlaue, NewVlaue from OpportunityFieldHistory where OpportunityId='oppID'

Comment: Try adding the Field column into your query, it should tell you the tracked field of each row. I assume they are not the same field.

Comment: I added Field column to the query query it still shows me 2 records for the same tracked lookup field one with id for old value and new value for lookup field and one with name value of the lookup field in old value and new value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is "working-as-designed"

For example, field history on `Opportunity.OwnerId` will return two records

```
OldValue      NewValue
----------     --------
oldId          newId
oldOwner.Name  newOwner.Name  // facilitates display in the Related List
```

Since you can't filter on `OldValue` or `NewValue` in the query; you'll need to post-process in Apex, testing `OldValue` / `NewValue` to see if they cast to `ID` type

```
try {
   Id oldValAsId = (Id) fieldHistoryItem.OldValue;
}
 catch (Exception e) { // ignore item  }
```